# OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature insertXY problem

Tags: openlayers-2

I've set up a simple web application where users can draw vectors (points, lines and polygons) using OpenLayers.

Actually digitizing is handled controls (`OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature`) and I'm using `featureadded`, `afterfeaturemodified`, `featureselected` and `featureunselected` listeners to save edits in the database.

I want to be able to manually add features, and `insertXY()` method of `OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature` (full reference: http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/DrawFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature.insertXY) to add x and y values, manually or using browser geolocation. This is working fine on PATH and POLYGON controls, but it's not working as expected on POINT control. In fact it's not working at all.

When I fire `insertXY` method no point is added on the map and no callback function is called. Am I missing something? I tried also to call the `finishSketch()` method after `insertXY()`, but I get the following error: `TypeError: this.handler.finishGeometry is not a function`

Maybe `insertXY` does not work with points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bradypus, you dont need to use OpenLayers.Handler.Point with drawing point feature to the map. doesnt `vector.addFeatures` func. work for you? beside this you can check out editing methods [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/editing-methods.html#). you can see info about `insertXY` there.

> The control.insertXY method inserts a point at the given map
>   coordinates (x, y) immediately prior to the most recent point (under
>   the mouse). The control.insertDeltaXY method inserts a point at the
>   given offset values (dx, dy) from the previously added point.
>
> The control.finishSketch method completes the current sketch without
>   adding the point under the user's mouse. This allows a sketch to be
>   finished without a double-click. The control.cancel method discards
>   the current sketch and leaves the control active. The control.insertXY
>   method may be called before any points are digitized manually. The
>   other methods have no effect until at least one point has been added
>   to the sketch.

full code for adding point to vector layer:

```
var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(x,y);
var point_ft = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point, null, null);
vectorLayer.addFeatures(point_ft);
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thank you @Aragon for your helpful answer. `vector.addFeatures()` works fine for points. I used handler for a faster digitizing and for switching easily throw different features (point, lines, polygons). The example you quoted above also uses Controls and Handles. I changed my code to use `vector.addFeatures()` if the draw points control is selected, and manual (or browser location) input is chosen for coordinates. Otherwise Controls and handles do the job. Do you think there is a better way to manage this?

Comment: that is the best method come to my mind. good luck :)